# DataGrid CellEditingTemplate data binding no more working recently

Tags: wpf, datagrid

For many years we have a WPF application running, which uses the following data-grid declaration (simplified):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee" >
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ctrl:EmployeeSelectionControl Employee="{Binding Employee,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Employee.DisplayName,FallbackValue='Add employee'}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Recently, the client informed us, that the selection of the Employee is no more possible via the `CellEditingTemplate`. Strangely, in deed the binding of the `EmployeeSelectionControl` does not work anymore from one day to another. There is no binding error in the output window visible and I have no idea, what the problem may be.
If I only use the `CellTemplate` and put the `EmployeeSelectionControl` there in, everything works fine:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee" >
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ctrl:EmployeeSelectionControl Employee="{Binding Employee,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The same happens also with other controls which are Bound in the `CellEditingTemplate`.
Has anyone an idea what this could be? Was there a change of the DataGrid in recent months?

**Please note**
The problem is not about the Binding Mode

```
Mode=TwoWay
```

This is specified by the Employee- Dependency property declaration as default (`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`)

Comment: Has the code been changed or has error appeared without any code change? Change to other .Net version?

Comment: No version change, no code change in the specific area.

Comment: Changes on implicit styles or in parent/container controls(event handling/interception)?

Comment: No, the app was recompiled because of minor changes in other areas but neither the styling, the base controls or other relevant changes occurred.

Comment: What do you mean with "binding doesn't work"? Employee will not be set in usercontrol or changes on Employee in usercontrol will not be reflected in datasource objects? Have you tried to use a ValueConverter for Employee and set Breakpoint there?

Comment: I havn't found much information except [trouble with DataGrid](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56ff3199-5abc-454e-87f7-bafff43e7422/net-45-critical-selecteditem-not-setting-binding-item). Idea is, that customer has another .Net version, where behavior is changed. Try to use latest .Net runtime, whether the issue still occurs.

Comment: I checked with an IValueConverter. When the column gets focused, it is successfully hit for reading the value from the source. However after the value is changed in the control, it is not hit again. It seems as if the binding is always OneWay (even if the binding mode is specified as TwoWay excplitely). I also think that it has something to do with the runtime version. Since everything works correctly, if I place the control directly in the CellTemplate, I will leave it like this until I find the reason for this behaviour. Thanks for your time and thoughts on the matter.